# Read single character with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to input a single character of type `char` in a Java program. Even if the user enters more than one character, it should only take the first. How can I do this? Is it possible with the help of the `Scanner` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Char using Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851950/reading-char-using-scanner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

```
char c = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Which will read the first available line, and extract the first character, or

```
try {
    char c = (char) System.in.read();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which will read the first `byte` in the first available line and cast it to a `char`

Comment: With the scanner it would be advisable to read a `short`. A `byte` won't cover every possible character.

Comment: @DaftPunk `Scanner` reads only `String`s, so i can directly extract a `char`. If you try to use `nextShort()` you'll get a `NumberFormatException`. If you are talking about using `System.in.read()` to read a short instead of a byte, then you can't, this can only read a byte.

Comment: I meant reading one byte, LS-8 then reading a second bit and adding them together. It produces a short, which then you cast to a byte.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
scanner.next().charAt(0)
```

---

Or, here's another idea, if you don't want `next()` to return anything extra:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("")
```

Now `scanner.next()` should return a single character string, and you can use `.charAt(0)` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

To consume a single character from `Scanner` you can use:

```
char ch = scanner.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
```